# Hibernate + Spring MVC + AngularJS - Do I need Maven?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I have to build an application for a course assignment, using Hibernate, Spring MVC and AngularJS. Almost all of the tutorials I found on the internet were presenting a Maven project.

My question is: Is it mandatory to create a Maven project, or is a Dynamic Web Project (Eclipse) enough? 
I am not familiar with Maven, but I have created Dynamic Web Projects before (using Hibernate, JSP views, etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can this without maven, but life is easier with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of Maven (or Gradle) is to coordinate all the (JVM) dependencies and package everything correctly. It's much easier to let tools do tedious work (that's why you're using Hibernate and a database instead of inventing your own storage).

I recommend creating a Spring Boot project using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io), which will set all of the build and launcher for you. Use m2eclipse (my preference) or the Gradle Eclipse Plugin to import the skeleton into Eclipse.